# Selenium wrong Chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I believe I am using the wrong chromedriver while trying to use selenium but I am not sure on how to update/downgrade my version.  Below is the code given after running a link through selenium

```
from pyChrome import PyChrome
>>> link = "http://www.destinylfg.net/"
>>> from pyChrome import PyChrome
>>> browser = PyChrome()

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:12483/devtools/browser/7b01bebd-7cb7-475b-ba8f-6e3b29ca4d9a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "pyChrome.py", line 96, in __init__
    self.__start(ghostmode=self.ghost)
  File "pyChrome.py", line 192, in __start
    self.window = Window(self.driver, config_filename=self.config_filename)
  File "C:\Users\James\Desktop\pyChrome/src\window.py", line 78, in __init__
   self.__readJSONFile()
  File "C:\Users\James\Desktop\pyChrome/src\window.py", line 63, in__readJSONFile
if self.validateScroll(scrollWin):
  File "C:\Users\James\Desktop\pyChrome/src\window.py", line 335, in validateScroll
scrollHeight = self.driver.execute_script("returndocument.body.scrollHeight")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.8.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 546, in execute_script
'args': converted_args})['value']
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.8.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 309, in execute
response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.8.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 460, in execute
return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.8.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 484, in _request
resp = self._conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 1121, in getresponse
response.begin()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 438, in begin
version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 394, in _read_status
line = self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 480, in readline
data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
 socket.error: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the         
 remote host
>>> [5272:7832:1217/135245.823:ERROR:service_manager.cc(157)] Connection InterfaceProviderSpec prevented service: content_renderer from binding interface: blink::mojom::ReportingServiceProxy exposed by: content_browser
```

link

Comment: Please add the `Chrome` and `chromedriver` version that you're testing in the question. Also add the code to instantiate your driver.

Answer (score 0):

> I am not sure on how to update/downgrade my version

ChromeDriver releases get posted here:

- https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

download the appropriate ChromeDriver archive, open it, and replace your existing ChromeDriver version with this new one.  It is simply one executable file named `chromedriver` (for Linux/Mac), or `chromdriver.exe` (for Windows).

Comment: i did that before this kind of error began to appear, how can I say to selenium that I've updated the driver? maybe this will solve my issue.